# How to debug XtraReports report even handlers, the scripts, in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

DevExpress's XtraReports adds event handlers, like beforeprint. in some script window. I can't add breakpoints in that window. How does one debug this code? The code is in a resx file.

Answer (score 1):

With the next version of the XtraReports Suite (v2011 vol 2) it has become possible to debug scripts using Visual Studio. For more details, see [Using Visual Studio for Script Debugging in XtraReports](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/seth/archive/2011/09/13/using-visual-studio-for-script-debugging-in-xtrareports.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately, AFAIK the way that the code is "executed" you cannot debug it at runtime (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q247866.aspx)

The way I debug mine is by simply placing my code inside a Try Catch, then log the Exception along with any Inner Exceptions as well as the StackTrace. This way I can get information on where the function failed.

This is an example of my Extension method for getting the full exception detail

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToFullMessage(ByVal ex As Exception) As String
    Dim result As String
    result = ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        result &= String.Format("{0}{0}Inner Exception{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.InnerException.ToFullMessage)
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="AllowDebugXtraReportScripts" value="true"/>
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Add it within

```
<configuration>
```

but below

```
<configSections>
```